# interpreting princomp results

Tags: r, pca

I am currently trying to do PCA in R. This is my first project in Data mining.
I have around 200 features and around 3000 rows of data.

Data is *not* in normalized form and i need to do dimensionality reduction 
So i am using PCA for the same. This is what i did till now

```
x <- princomp(data,scores=TRUE,cor=TRUE)
```

I suppose to do dimension reduction, i am supposed to look at score values. So i did to get top few values

```
head(x$scores)
```

This was the output

```
       Comp.1     Comp.2     Comp.3     Comp.4    ...
[1,]  6.831452 -4.4316218 -1.9226226 -0.8344245 
[2,] -1.808007 -4.2743390  1.0173944  0.4527465
[3,] -7.750329 -4.9523056 -1.6750438  1.6247354 
.
.
.
```

Now I am not sure how to interpret these matrix and get the best attributes (and do dimension reduction). It would be great if someone could help me out with this.

P.S - I searched a lot but did not get an answer for the same.

Answer (score 4):

`scores` is just one piece of the puzzle. The general formula is:

```
original_data =~ approximation = (scores * loadings) * scale + center
```

where:

```
1. `scores` are the coordinates in your new orthogonal base
1. `loadings` are the directions of the new axis in the old base
1. `scale` are the scaling applied to the dimensions
1. `center` are the coordinates of the new base origin in the old base
```

Using the R objects, the formula above is

```
data =~ t(t(x$scores %*% t(x$loadings)) * x$scale + x$center)
```

You'll want to reduce dimensions by only taking the first `i` loadings:

```
data =~ t(t(x$scores[, 1:i] %*% t(x$loadings[, 1:i ])) * x$scale + x$center)
```

Comment: I think they should first look at the `summary`. And of course it's possible that they actually should do factor analysis and not PCA.

Comment: @Roland - Thanks for the input. I did look at the summary. Can you please elaborate why should i use factor analysis and not PCA?

Comment: I don't know if you should, since your task is not very clearly defined. Do some reading.

Comment: @Roland - I am trying to do build a predictive classification model using the data. Thanks for the input. Will definitely read some more materials